# why index size increased after deleted many records from a collection?

Tags: mongodb

Today I deleted many records from a collection, at first the total count is `1379345` , deleted count: `925367` then left count: 453978.

Before delete:

```
"count" : 1379345,
"size" : 3823247286,
"avgObjSize" : 2771,
"storageSize" : 1871536128,
"nindexes" : 4,
"totalIndexSize" : 86913024,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 12873728,
    "created_at_1" : 17534976,
    "storage_time_1" : 7397376,
    "guid_1" : 49106944
},
```

After delete:

```
"count" : 453978,
"size" : 2478837459,
"avgObjSize" : 5460,
"storageSize" : 1871536128,
"nindexes" : 4,
"totalIndexSize" : 89522176,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 12873728,
    "created_at_1" : 18096128,
    "storage_time_1" : 7397376,
    "guid_1" : 51154944
},

count: 1379345 ==> 453978 diff: 925367
size: 3823247286 ==> 2478837459 diff: 1,344,409,827
totalIndexSize: 86913024 ==> 89522176 diff: -2,609,152
```

Now I'm a little confused why `totalIndexSize` increases not decreases ? I think it should shrink just like `size`?